# Is there any way I can get the latest version of postgresql onto my pi?

Tags: packages, database

I'm a noob to linux and pi so may just be missing the obvious but it appears the latest version available for the pi is 11.x which does not support generated columns. I am in the process of porting an app from windows which relies on generated columns so I need version 12.

Comment: perhaps in http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/p/ currently there appears to be a 'postgresql-13' directory with specific options available in it

Comment: Following up on what Ingo said, I was in the same situation where I needed PGSQL >= 12.0, and I found this helpful [guide](https://blog.rustprooflabs.com/2019/07/postgresql-postgis-install-from-source-raspberry-pi) on how to compile pgsql version 12 from source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to the options presented by Ingo, there is also a PostgreSQL Docker image with ARM support:
https://github.com/docker-library/postgres
https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/

This will probably be easier than (cross-)compiling it from source yourself, and running services like Postgres in a Docker container is a pretty standard practice these days.

Comment: This is probably the best way to go. As far as I have found it's the only option to run Postgres 13. Beware the limited amount of RAM on an RPI though - if OS upgrades results in more RAM being consumed by the OS, it could render the Docker container difficult to start up.

Answer (score 2):

The postgresql project has binaries available for Debian using a repository with adding an entry in `/etc/apt/sources.list` as you can see at [Postgresql - Linux downloads (Debian)](https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/debian/). But you will also find there that it is only

> available on the following architectures:
>
> - amd64
> - i386
> - ppc64el

**armhf** for the Raspberry Pi isn't part of the list so you are lost to compile it from [source](https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/source/) but I'm afraid that will take hours on a RasPi even on a RPi 4B with 4GB ram.

You can also compile on a more powerful computer with an intel processor (amd64) for the Raspberry Pi (armhf). This is called **cross compiling** but need some knowledge about compiling and isn't an easy task for a beginner. You could ask google how to do it and if running into problems just ask here.

Comment: Thanks for that. I wonder if I can compile on a x86 linux mint laptop for a specified architecture?